# What is the DirectX 12 equivalent of Vulkan's "transient attachment"?

Tags: vulkan, directx-12

I have a compute shader which I'd like to output to an image/buffer which is meant to be intermediate stoarge between two pipelines: a compute pipeline, and a graphics pipeline. The graphics pipeline is actually a "dummy", in that it does nothing apart from copy the contents of the intermediate buffer into a swapchain image. This is necessitated by the fact that DX12 deprecated the ability of compute pipelines to use UAVS to directly write into swapchain images.

I think the intermediate storage should be a "transient" attachment, in the Vulkan sense:

> `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSIENT_ATTACHMENT_BIT` specifies that the memory bound to this image will have been allocated with the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_LAZILY_ALLOCATED_BIT` (see Memory Allocation for more detail). This bit can be set for any image that can be used to create a `VkImageView` suitable for use as a color, resolve, depth/stencil, or input attachment.`

This is explained in [this article](https://gpuopen.com/vulkan-renderpasses/):

> Finally, Vulkan includes the concept of transient attachments. These are framebuffer attachments that begin in an uninitialized or cleared state at the beginning of a renderpass, are written by one or more subpasses, consumed by one or more subpasses and are ultimately discarded at the end of the renderpass. In this scenario, the data in the attachments only lives within the renderpass and never needs to be written to main memory. Although we’ll still allocate memory for such an attachment, the data may never leave the GPU, instead only ever living in cache. This saves bandwidth, reduces latency and improves power efficiency.

Does DirectX 12 have a similar image usage concept?

Comment: "*it does nothing apart from copy the contents of the intermediate buffer into a swapchain image*" I admit that I know little about D3D12's details, but can't you just copy directly to the swapchain image? Or does it expressly forbid that too?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am not sure, but that would make life much easier! I think I'll make a question regarding that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Direct3D 12 does not have this concept. And the reason for that limitation ultimately boils down to why transient allocation exists. TL;DR: It's not for doing the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Vulkan's render pass system exists for one purpose: to make tile-based renderers first-class citizens of the rendering system. TBRs do not fit well in OpenGL or D3D's framebuffer model. In both APIs, you can just swap framebuffers in and out whenever you want.

TBRs do not render to memory directly. They perform rendering operations into internal buffers, which are seeded from memory and then possibly written to memory after the rendering operation is complete. Switching rendered images whenever you want works against this structure, which is why TBR vendors have a list of things you're *not supposed to do* if you want high-performance in your OpenGL ES code.

Vulkan's render pass system is an abstraction of a TBR system. In the abstract model, the render pass system potentially reads data from the images in the frame buffer, then performs a bunch of subpasses on copies of this data, and at the end, potentially writes the updated data back out into the images. So from the outside of the process, it looks like you're rendering to the images, but you're not. To maintain this illusion, for the duration of a render pass, you can *only* use those framebuffer images in the way that the render pass model allows: as attachments.

Now consider deferred rendering. In deferred rendering, you render to g-buffers, which you then read in your lighting passes to generate the final image. Once you've generated the final image, you don't need those g-buffers anymore. In a regular GPU, that doesn't mean anything; because rendering goes directly to memory, those g-buffers must take up actual storage.

But consider how a TBR works. It does rendering into a single tile; in optimal cases, it processes *all* of the fragments for a single tile at once. Which means it goes through the geometry *and* lighting passes. For a TBR, the g-buffer is just a piece of scratch memory you use to get the final answer; it doesn't need to be read from memory or copied to memory.

In short, it doesn't need *memory*.

Enter lazily allocated memory and transient attachment images. They exist to allow TBRs to keep g-buffers in tile memory and never to have to allocate actual storage for them (or at least, it only happens if some runtime circumstance occurs that forces it, like shoving too much geometry at the GPU). And it only works within a render pass; if you end a render pass and have to use one of the g-buffers in another render pass, then the magic has to go away and the data has to touch actual storage.

The Vulkan API makes how specific this use case is very explicit. You cannot bind a piece of lazily-allocated memory to an image that does not have the `USAGE_TRANSIENT_ATTACHMENT` flag set on it (or to a buffer *of any kind*). And you'll notice that it says "transient *attachment*", as in render pass *attachments*. It says this because you'll also notice that transient attachments cannot be used for *non-attachment* uses (part of the [valid usage tests for `VkImageCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap11.html#VkImageCreateInfo)). At all.

What you want to do is not the sort of thing that lazily allocated memory is made for. It can't work.

As for Direct3D 12, the API is not designed to run on mobile GPUs, and since only mobile GPUs are tile-based renderers (some recent desktop GPUs have TBR similarities, but are not full TBRs), it has no facilities designed explicitly for them. And thus, it has no need for lazily allocated memory or transient attachments.

Comment: Wouldn't desktop GPUs have enough flexibility to act as TBRs even if they're not designed from the ground up that way?  And if so, do you think they'd be able to get a performance boost from the renderpass model in Vulkan?

Comment: Non-TBRs already get some small improvements from having some idea what you're doing with a general set of rendering operations. But no, desktop GPUs won't gain much from basically ignoring half of their hardware to try to pretend to be a full TBR. What people *do* take advantage of is to render things like performing light passes in cache-sized tiles, so that each light pass tile is only reading so much from the g-buffers. But other than optimizations like that, no, there's really not much point to it.